# How does one design a spring batch job with a data source, possible concurrent steps and aggregation in the end?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am new to spring batching and I'm having some doubts on how to implement a use case. My experience so far with spring batching is centered around jobs composed of tasklets with reader, writer and processor. I feel though that the following use case is above my experience so here goes:

- I need to read from an mdb
- I need to differentiate between the entries based on a combination of column values(will yield a max of 5 combos)
- Processing needs in the end to generate a collection of items of type T.
- Everything needs to be merged in the end for some aggregations.

My ideea is to avoid reading the mdb multiple times, so I was looking into a way of splitting the data based on combos and then run, maybe concurrently, the processes. Having this in mind I read about the Splitter and partitioning components from spring batching and integration.

What I don't exactly know is how to put all concepts toghether.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by MDB? MessageDrivenBean? If the answer if yes - what do you mean by reading from MDB multiple times? Since MDBs are message-driven, we can't read from them at any time, so basis on my understanding of your question I'd do it in the following way:

1. MDB receives message and stores received entry in some DB table - that would be some kind of transition table; such tables are often used during processing of financial transactions
2. Batch window comes - job is triggered.
3. Now you can query the table in any way you want. Since you are looking for splitting and processing the data concurrently, I'd advice using [Spring Batch partitioning](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning) with `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` executing step locally in concurrent threads. What you need to do is to read data from database differentiating on combination of column values - that should be relatively easy - it's just a matter of constructing appropriate SQL query.
4. Processed chunks are aggregated into `ItemWriter write(List<? extends T> items)` depending on commit interval; if such aggregation is not enough for you, I'd add another table and Batch step that aggregates previously processed entries.

Basically that's how batch processing works - you read items, transforms them and write. The next step - if it's not just a simple tasklet - does exactly the same.

Comment: mdb = Microsoft Access Database; sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'll try and build on your answer. If I replace the first step and put in place a step that is responsible for reading from the mdb and streaming data. The next step would be the partition and after that the aggregator step. But where does the column combo separation come in? Does it belong in the partition step, which implies multiple reads, or does it belong in the first step(where I would create a map that will hold the data for the partition step.)?

Comment: Or how about a third solution where the job is composed of a single step, responsible for RD,process and WR. And there would be multiple concurrent runs of that job controlled by the ExecutorFramework. Not sure what's the best approach from an architectural point of view.

Comment: Everything depends on what you mean by "combo separation" and "aggregation of result". If you for example want to differentiate items basis on some column value - you just need to partition data properly - it's responsibility of reader/partitioner. For example, you can process one type of data per thread (one-to-one relation); this way you can store some transition values in ExecutionContext and aggregate them at the end. I don't mean that you have to do it in one step - add as many steps as you need - it just should be clean solution with clearly separated, recoverable steps.